# Abstract implementation of log repo

Tags: go, logging

I want to `wrap / abstract` the log API (hide the implementation) and use some library
The reason that we want to hide the implementation is that we want to provide our log API and hide the logger lib which is used under the hod , now its `[logrus][1]` and it can be also `zap` `klog` and who use the log api do not need to change the his log code usage when I switch to different logger implementation (we are just changing the engine... )

What I did is create struct and the `init logger` return my struct and in addition create functions (see below) that wrap the functionality ,

```
package logger

import (
   "fmt"
   "os"

   "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

const (
   AppLogLevel = "APP_LOG"
   defLevel    = "error"
)

type Logger struct {
   label      string
   version    string
   loggerImpl *logrus.Logger
}

// init logger
func NewLogger(level string,version string) *Logger {

   lvl := logLevel(level)
   logger := &logrus.Logger{
      Out:       os.Stdout,
      Level:     lvl,
      Formatter: &logrus.TextFormatter{},
   }
   return &Logger{
      version: version,
      loggerImpl: logger,
   }
}

// GetLogLevel - Get level from env
func getLogLevel() string {
   lvl, _ := os.LookupEnv(AppLogLevel)
   if lvl != "" {
      return lvl
   }
   return defLevel
}

func logLevel(lvl string) logrus.Level {

   switch lvl {
   case "debug":
      return logrus.DebugLevel
   case "info":
      return logrus.InfoLevel
   case "error":
      return logrus.ErrorLevel
   case "warn":
      return logrus.WarnLevel
   case "fatal":
      return logrus.FatalLevel
   case "panic":
      return logrus.PanicLevel
   default:
      panic(fmt.Sprintf("the specified %s log level is not supported", lvl))
   }
}

func (logger *Logger) SetLevel(level string) {
   lvl := logLevel(level)
   logger.loggerImpl.SetLevel(lvl)
}



func (logger *Logger) Debugf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Debugf(format, args...)
}
func (logger *Logger) Infof(format string, args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Infof(format, args...)
}


func (logger *Logger) Errorf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Errorf(format, args...)
}

func (logger *Logger) Fatalf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Fatalf(format, args...)
}

func (logger *Logger) Panicf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Panicf(format, args...)
}

func (logger *Logger) Debug(args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Debug(args...)
}

func (logger *Logger) Info(args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Info(args...)
}

func (logger *Logger) Warn(args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Warn(args...)
}

func (logger *Logger) Error(args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Error(args...)
}

func (logger *Logger) Fatal(args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Fatal(args...)
}

func (logger *Logger) Panic(args ...interface{}) {
   logger.loggerImpl.Panic(args...)
}
```

...

Do I miss something ? As when I try to change it to zap (change the structure to the following:

```
type Logger struct {
    label      string
    version    string
    loggerImpl *zap.Logger
}
```

This code is not working (all the functions code which works for logrus)

`logger.loggerImpl.SetLevel(lvl)`

and also

`logger.loggerImpl.Tracef(format, args...)`

etc as [`zap`](https://github.com/uber-go/zap) lib doenst have them ,any idea how to abstract it which can support both or more in the future?

**update**

I try with the following (adapter pattern) : (but it looks that inside the method I have now recursive calls ) any idea how to avoid it ?

```
package logger

import (
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type Logger struct {
    adapter Adapter
}

func (l *Logger) SetLogger(a Adapter) {
    l.adapter = a
}

func (l *Logger) Debugf(fmt string, args ...interface{}) {
    l.adapter.Debugf(fmt, args...)
}

type Adapter interface {
    SetLevel(level string)
    Tracef(format string, args ...interface{})
    Debugf(string, ...interface{})
    Infof(format string, args ...interface{})
    Warnf(format string, args ...interface{})
    Errorf(format string, args ...interface{})
    Fatalf(format string, args ...interface{})
    Panicf(format string, args ...interface{})
    Trace(args ...interface{})
    Debug(args ...interface{})
    Info(args ...interface{})
    Warn(args ...interface{})
    Error(args ...interface{})
    Fatal(args ...interface{})
}

type StdLoggerAdapter struct {
}

func (l StdLoggerAdapter) SetLevel(level string) {
    lvl := logLevel(level)
    l.SetLevel(string(lvl))
}

func (l StdLoggerAdapter) Tracef(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    l.Tracef(format, args...)
}

func (l StdLoggerAdapter) Infof(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    l.Infof(format,args)
}

func (l StdLoggerAdapter) Warnf(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    l.Warnf(format,args)
}

...
func (l StdLoggerAdapter) Debugf(fmt string, args ...interface{}) {
    log.Printf(fmt, args...)
}

func NewLogger(a Adapter) Logger {
    return Logger{adapter: a}
}

func main() {
    logger := NewLogger(StdLoggerAdapter{})
    logger.Debugf("stdlib logger debug msg")
}

func logLevel(lvl string) log.Level {
    var level log.Level
    switch lvl {
    //case "trace":
    //  level = log.TraceLevel
    case "debug":
        level = log.DebugLevel
    case "info":
        level = log.InfoLevel
    case "warn":
        level = log.WarnLevel
    case "error":
        level = log.ErrorLevel
    case "fatal":
        level = log.FatalLevel
    case "panic":
        level = log.PanicLevel
    default:
        level = log.ErrorLevel
    }
    return level
}
```

Comment: Logrus is already an abstraction. Why wrap it?

Comment: "This code is not working" is not a problem statement. What is the observed behavior? What did you expect instead?

Comment: `loggerImpl`... that's such a Java name. Also: the easiest way to abstract is to declare a common interface (e.g. `Error(f)`, `Debug(f)`, etc..) and then just use whichever logging package conforms to that interface (zerolog doesn't I believe, but most others will)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - 1 . how would you change the name instead of "loggerImpel" :) , 2. what I need is a bit more tricky ,  change the "engine" from `logrus` to `zap` (or any other logger)  without the user need to change the call to the logger api which I was provided, imagine that a lot of users are using "my logger" which wrap logrus, after few month logrus is deprecated and I want to change the engine but that the users will not need to change there calls to the logger, how it can be achieved in golang ? 3. any example will be very helpful ...

Answer (score 4):

Suggest thinking about the problem differently and avoiding the type/interface shenanigans entirely. Create a stateless logger with an API you like and that feels reasonable to implement across different loggers. If you want to update the underlying logger, update it, users only need to update their dependencies to see it. If you want to maintain separation, you can isolate logger backends by import paths.

https://gitlab.com/tight5/kit/blob/master/logger/logger.go follows this and might inspire your own purposes. It's heavily based around go-kit's logger, which we liked to begin with, and wanted to be able to drop it in as needed for instrumentation. It also redirects the stdlib log package, which we valued so users did not have to update all of they're existing log statements to our library.

```golang
package main
import (
    "gitlab.com/tight5/kit/logger"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    logger.Info().Log("msg", "this is a logging example")
    log.Println("also logs through kit logger")

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6sBfI85Yx6g

`go-kit`s log interface is powerful and I'd evaluate that before any home grow: https://github.com/go-kit/kit/blob/master/log/log.go is just `func Log(keyvals ...interface{})`, and supports `zap` and `logrus` backends right now.

https://github.com/go-kit/kit/tree/master/log/logrus
https://github.com/go-kit/kit/tree/master/log/zap

In the linked package-level logger for example, changing the backend for users is as easy as changing the default in: https://gitlab.com/tight5/kit/blob/master/logger/logger.go#L42-53 (we called it format in our abstraction, but you're really just picking the logger implementation)

Here is an excerpt from the above to show an example implementation for logrus (zap would be very similar).

```
... other imports ... 
import kitlogrus "github.com/go-kit/kit/log/logrus"
import "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
func Init(format LogFormat, logLevel LogLevel) {
    var l log.Logger
    switch format {
    case FormatJson:
        l = log.NewJSONLogger(os.Stdout)
    case FormatLogfmt:
        l = log.NewLogfmtLogger(os.Stdout)
    case FormatNop:
        l = log.NewNopLogger()
    case FormatLogrus:
        l = kitlogrus.NewLogrusLogger(logrus.New())
    case FormatZap:
    default:
        panic(fmt.Errorf("invalid log format: %v", format))
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this sparks an idea for your own implementation!

Comment: HI, thanks,`1.`  I think using it like `logger.Info().Log` create it's a bit "verbose" , is there a way to use a shorter way ? like `logger.info("bla bla")` ? `2.` why I need also to put `"msg"` inside, what is the benfit and if there a way to avoid it ? `3.` it will be great if you can provide example how can I switch between `zap` and `logrus` , from your example I dont understand how the `switch` does it...thanks!

Comment: HI It will be great if you can answer my question than I mark it as resolved as I decide to use it ... thanks!

Comment: it will be great if you just put some example how would you switch your all implementation to `logrus` , I try to put in the init the following which doesnt work `func Init(format LogFormat) {
 var l log.Logger
 switch format {
 case FormatJson:
  l = log.NewJSONLogger(os.Stdout)
 case FormatLogfmt:
  l = log.NewLogfmtLogger(os.Stdout)
 case FormatNop:
  l = log.NewNopLogger()
 case Logrus:
  l = logrus.New()`

Comment: @JhonD Probably no longer useful, but I updated my answer with an example for logus. The upshot is you need to actually meet the `Logger` interface for `go-kit` when using the logger I linked. Go Kit provides implementations for logrus (and zap) so you just need to import their packages

Answer (score 1):

You can use an adapter:

```
package main

import (
 "log"
 "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type Logger struct {
   adapter Adapter
}

func (l *Logger) SetLogger(a Adapter) {
   l.adapter=a
}

func (l *Logger) Debugf(fmt string,args...interface{}) {
   l.adapter.Debugf(fmt,args...)
}

type Adapter interface {
   Debugf(string,...interface{})
}

type StdLoggerAdapter struct {}

func (l StdLoggerAdapter) Debugf(fmt string,args...interface{}) {
   log.Printf(fmt,args...)
}

type LogrusAdapter struct {}

func (l LogrusAdapter) Debugf(fmt string,args...interface{}) {
   logrus.Debugf(fmt,args...)
}


func NewLogger(a Adapter) Logger {
   return Logger{adapter:a}
}


func main() {
    logger:=NewLogger(StdLoggerAdapter{})
    logger.Debugf("stdlib logger debug msg")
    logger.SetLogger(LogrusAdapter{})
    logger.Debugf("logrus debug msg")
}
```

Comment: thanks, it will be great if you can provide full example how can I use it with your logic and switch between of them...thanks!

Comment: @JhonD, edited the example to include more details.

Comment: Thanks, it will be great if you can provide a working example...I put the interface functions but still have lot errors...

Comment: Thanks, it will be great if you can provide a working example...I put the interface functions but still have lot errors...one adapter will be sufficient

Comment: Thanks!, but the adapter shoulden't be `logrus` or `zap`? how can it be done ?

Comment: when changing it to logrus I got errors in  `logger := NewLogger(StdLoggerAdapter{})`

Comment: I define the interface like `type Adapter interface {
 SetLevel(level string)
 Tracef(format string, args ...interface{})
 Debugf(string, ...interface{})
 Infof(format string, args ...interface{})
 Warnf(format string, args ...interface{})
 Errorf(format string, args ...interface{})
 Fatalf(format string, args ...interface{})
 Panicf(format string, args ...interface{})
 Trace(args ...interface{})
 Debug(args ...interface{})
 Info(args ...interface{})
 Warn(args ...interface{})
 Error(args ...interface{})
 Fatal(args ...interface{})
}`

Comment: Please see my update, I change it, should it be like this ? inside the methods it looks like recursive calls, should it be like this ?  e.g. `func (l StdLoggerAdapter) Infof(format string, args ...interface{}) {
 l.Infof(format,args)
}
`

Comment: Please see my update in the question, the code fails

Comment: HI Any update ? the code in the post is working with your suggestion but I got erorrs

Comment: See the edit including logrus. What you did above is a recursive call, and will cause stack overflow.

Comment: ok, so I dont understand why you have `(l LogrusAdapter)` inside the method if you dont use them ...

Comment: in addition there is only one print although your main include two, the only one is ` stdlib logger debug msg
`

Comment: it will be great if you also add comments what I should put in the adapter structs and in general

Comment: My code is for illustrating the point. Your implementation may use the receiver l. It probably printed one msg because default logrus log level is info and will not print debug level messages. The adapter struct contents will depend on your implementation and the logger backend. It might simply be empty if you do not need anything. They simply become implementations of the adapter interface that way.

Answer (score 1):

I have created this repository for personal use I think it can be improved to serves your purpose.

You can have a look.

PS: While adding new logger like (zerolog) you can change value of the variable `logger` and change the methods (`Info(args ...)`, `Debug(args ...)` etc.) according to your needs.

[log-wrapper](https://gitlab.com/gagan2906/log-wrapper/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused to be honest about what you're trying to do.

In general, to answer the *meat* of your question:

To make it possible to switch between different logging libraries in your code, you must define a specific interface and then implement it for each library. Since you can't implement methods on structs in another package, you will have to wrap the other libraries and define the methods on your wrappers.

Your example code has 'level' as a property of *your* logger; I guess you want *your* logger to decide what level of logging you want, and just use the library logger as a pipe for pumping messages.

So, let's assume a simplified version:

```
type LogLevel int

const (
    LevelInfo LogLevel = iota
    LevelDebug
    LevelWarn
    LevelError
    LevelFatal
)

type interface ILogger {
    Log(args ...interface{})
}

type struct Logger {
    Level LogLevel
    internal ILogger
}
```

This will be the basis of everything else.

There's a question worth pausing over:

Do the different loggers provide compatible interfaces? If you switch between 'zap' and 'logrus' is it because you maybe actually want to use their specific interfaces? Maybe they provide some more specialized functionality that you actually want.

If you hide them behind a common interface like `ILogger` here, you will *lose* any benefit these loggers provide in terms of actually logging.

Anyway, we will proceed, ignoring this concern, let's see how you can use these primitives:

```
func NewLogger(internal ILogger) *Logger {
    return &Logger{
        Level: LeveLInfo,
        internal: internal,
    }
}

func (logger *Logger) Log(level LogLevel, args ...interface{}) {
    if level >= logger.Level {
        logger.internal.Log(args...)
    }
}
func (logger *Logger) Logf(level LogLevel, fmt string, args ...interface{}) {
    if level >= logger.Level {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf(fmt, args...)
        logger.internal.Log(msg)
    }
}
```

Now you can implement `Info` and `Infof` and `Debug` and `Debugf` .. etc as simple convenience methods.

Here's an example. The rest will be left as an exercise to the reader.

```
func (logger *Logger) Infof(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    logger.Logf(LevelInfo, format, args...)
}
func (logger *Logger) Info(args ...interface{}) {
    logger.Log(LevelInfo, args...)
}
```

Now the hard part: forcing all third party libraries to conform to your interface.

I'm not familiar with all the different logging libraries, so this may prove to be not so simple. You might have to change the design of the `ILogger` interface to make it more feasible.

In any case, this is how you would generally do it:

```
type ZapLogger *zap.Logger

func (z ZapLogger) Log(args ...interface{}) {
    zz := *zap.Logger(z)
    // TODO: do something to pump `args` into `zz`
}

type LogrusLogger *logrus.Logger

func (g LogrusLogger) Log(args ...interface{}) {
    gg := *logrus.Logger(g)
    // TODO: do something to pump `args` into `gg`
}
```

Now, you have these types like `LogrusLogger` and `ZapLogger` which implement `ILogger` and can be easily cast back and forth with the underlying logging library at no cost.

So you can instantiate your own logger to wrap the underlying 3rd party logger

```
var underlying *logrus.Logger = MakeMyLogrusLogger(...)
var myLogger = NewLogger(LogrusLogger(underlying))
```

Now everyone can call `myLogger.Infof(....)` to log stuff.

If you ever decide to switch to `zap` or whatever, you would change the above line (and also you would have to define the implementation of the ILogger interface for zap)

```
var underlying *zap.Logger = MakeMyZapLogger(...)
var myLogger = NewLogger(ZapLogger(underlying))
```

---

With all that said, I think this whole endeavor is fruitless and not really worth it. Since these libraries don't seem to provide compatible interfaces, and the whole point of using one library over the other is because you like the *different* interface that this other library provides for you.

Comment: thanks it will be great if you can provide the working code

Comment: I can't provide full working code because it's a lot of work to dig into zap and logrus and try to force them to match the hypothetical interface. I have only provided the general direction for how to do something _like_ this. The details must be filled by you depending on the details of your situation.

Comment: ahh no, im talking about just one implementation for zap or logrus whatever its easy to you...thanks

Comment: @user10753492 Great explanation and idea there.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract out the methods required or common methods by creating a interface and implement the interface like:

```
type Logger interface {
    SetLevel(level string)
    Errorf(format string, args ...interface{})
}

type LogrusLogger struct {
    label      string
    version    string
    loggerImpl *logrus.Logger
}

type zapLogger struct {
    label      string
    version    string
    loggerImpl *logrus.Logger
}
```

Initialize the log based on requirement:

```
Logger log := new LogrusLogger{}
```

or

```
Logger log := new ZapLogger{}
```

use it as:

```
log.Errorf("message")
```

Comment: to decouple more consider using private interface, it might be a bit of copy paste within multiple package, but it unties things more.

Comment: Thanks, what I need is a bit more tricky , change the "engine" from logrus to zap without the user need to change the call to the logger, imagine that a lot of users are using "my logger" which wrap logrus, after few month logrus is deprecated and I want to change the engine but that the users will not need to change there calles to the logger, how it can be achieved in golang ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had to create a library that would be used by multiple microservices and needed some HTTP logging. Instead of making all microservices use one log library, I had to allow either logrus or zap.

I created a [logger](https://github.com/arun0009/go-logger) interface with two implementations (logrus and zap).